# How does the "admitted until" date work for passport stamps?

Tags: visas, air-travel, visa-expiration

I have stamp in my passport that says admitted until 10 MAR 2017

**Does it mean that I have to leave before 2017-03-10T23:59:59 (country I am in timezone), or I have to leave before 2017-03-09T23:59:59?** (before day I am admitted until starts)

For bonus points, what if my flight is on +1 day but I go through customs day before while my visa is still active and spend it in departure hall?

[image]

Comment: @pnuts So is it end of 03/09 or 03/10, lol?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about Thailand?

Comment: @JonathanReez Hi Jonathan, No (unless rules differ from country to country). I couldn't find generic answer hence the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you have to leave (i.e. clear passport control) on that day, the 10 March.

In other words, before 23:59:59 on 10 March

Comment: [citation needed]